# Error while starting the daemons for using Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I have installed hadoop on my ubuntu but the problem is everytime I start using it,I can't use it until I format my namenode? What may be the problem? Kindly suggest me with this.
I'm using Hadoop version 1.2.1 on JDK version 1.8.0_25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have mention hadoop.tmp.dir property as tmp directory so when you shut down the pc it want namenode format. in this case, make a directory hdfs in var directory,`/var/hdfs` and give the permission by

```
sudo chown -R username /var/hdfs
```

go to hadoop/conf
open hdfs-site.xml and edit this property.

```
 <property>
   <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
   <value>/var/hdfs</value>
 </property>
```

one time, format namenode

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format

start.all.sh
```

After this, System will never want namenode format.
let me know if not work.

Comment: where can I find the var directory

Comment: You don't have to find just paste this property in conf/hdfs-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you are using such an old version of Hadoop? 2.5.2 is the current stable build. Also is this a fresh install of hadoop? If so run the following command to format the namenode.

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

This will format your namenode. It will wipe all data from HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System), but not your local file system. You should only need to do this once, unless your namenode gets corrupted for some reason.

You can get the most uptodate version of hadoop from:
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org/hadoop/common/

A little more information could be helpful, perhaps a screenshot showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop all hadoop services.
2. Remove your tmp folder(contains datanode and namenode) and then format your namenode.

   ```
   hadoop namenode -format
   ```
3. Then start the hadoop services.

Comment: Shall I delete the tmp folder from the terminal or can I do it manually

Comment: you can delete it by any way.